# Django - should I create related objects immediately or on demand?

Tags: python, django

Let's say you have a `ForeignKey` `MyModel.related_model` and this `related_model` has all fields either `null=True` or `default=something`.

Like `User.userprofile` which I use on several places in my project. Is it better to create it immediately after `User` has been created?

either this way:

```
def save(...
    super().save(...
    UserProfile.objects.create(user=self)
```

or this:

```
@receiver(post_save...
def create_userprofile(...
    UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=self)
```

or should I create it when `User` first time goes to "Update profile" page?

Is there a pattern for that (excluding some special situations)?

Answer (score 1):

In Django, `ForeignKey` fields are not optional by default, so unless `UserProfile` is a field that should ultimately only sometimes exist on the `User`, it's best to create and assign it immediately, before you save the newly created `User`. You shouldn't make `UserProfile` an optional `ForeignKey` unless it may never get created and remain unset indefinitely. Having optional fields that are always guaranteed to exist when needed would be a confusing model definition.

If `UserProfile` is going to be optional, I'd still lean toward creating and setting immediately in the cases where it's going to exist. Doing so prevents any developer on the project from using `get` when they need to use `get_or_create` and thus prevents that entire class of bugs from existing.

The only case where I could imagine not creating and setting it immediately, would be the case where its creation took a significant amount of time. In which case, I might do it asynchronously using `Celery`, or a similar framework.